# Query Execution Timeout with Postgres 8.4

Tags: hibernate, postgresql-8.4

I want to implement, query time out. Application framework consists, **Spring MVC and hibernate**.

If I am specifying **timeout in session factory**. it gives error Timeout is **not implemented in Postgresql driver**.

I am using postgres **8.4**

Code is:

```
@Override
@Transactional(timeout=20)
public List<MasterBooking> searchMasterBookings(---){//some more code}
```

error stack trace is:

```
SQL state [0A000]; error code [0];Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.
```

How can I implement this ?

Comment: I guess some code / file snippets would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postgres driver does not implement this method, see also http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2008-04/msg00161.php for details. A request for a solution is on the TODO list.

Using a connection pool like e.g. [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) helps you implement a controlled timeout behavior in a much better way.